# React Native Version Mismatch with Native older, with RNFirebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am getting the Version Mismatch with JavaScript version at 0.53.3 and Native sitting at 0.50.4.

Ran `watchman watch-del-all` as instructed and re-run `react-native run-ios` again with no luck.  Also did `cd ios && pod install` for many times each time showing `Pod installation complete! There are 11 dependencies from the Podfile and 25 total pods installed.`.

Have found solutions about the Version mismatch which most of them are Native higher than the JavaScript so updating `package.json` would work.  However, how may I update the Native so that it matches the JavaScript Version?

I am not currently using Expo.

Regarding "downgrade RN", I updated as there was a Firebase [[DEFAULT]] problem and one of the suggested fix is to update RN (re-downloading `GoogleServices-Info.plist` didn't help).  Thus I am looking for instructions for keeping RN at this version.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of mismatch is related to the changing of your react-native version without properly updating peer dependencies and native projects.

Since you aren't using Expo, try following the upgrade guidelines here offered from Facebook.

[Upgrading to new React Native versions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html)
Found under.. "Projects built with native code"

I personally found success using the "Alternative" steps, and then confirmed my project
`** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` correctly by both...

1. on the console using `react-native run-ios`
2. and then from within Xcode